# how to customize the Lyx layout to write affiliation with new cas-dc class format?

Tags: lyx, lyx-layouts, els-cas

I almost find a solution.

```
Style Author
    Margin          Static
    LatexType       Command
    Category        FrontMatter
    InTitle         0
    Argument 1
      LabelString   "ref address"
      Tooltip       "Label you will reference in the address"
    EndArgument
    Argument post:1
      LabelString   "Orcid"
      Tooltip       "Orcid number as xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx"
      LeftDelim     "[orcid="
      RightDelim    "]"
    EndArgument   
    LatexName       author
    LabelSep        xxx
    ParSkip         0.4
    TopSep          1.3
    BottomSep       0.7
    ParSep          0.7
    Align           Center
    LabelType       No_Label
    Font
      Size          Large
    EndFont
End
```

The LaTeX is like `\author[hrb]{C.V. Radhakrishnan}[orcid=1234-3343-8888-6666]`.

## Question ==========

2021-05-11, Elsevier released a new class file as cas-dc.cls.
There is the affiliation format listed in the TeX template file as

```
  \author[1,3]{Author Name}[type=editor,
  style=chinese,
  auid=000,
  bioid=1,
  prefix=Sir,
  orcid=0000-0000-0000-0000,
  facebook=<facebook id>,
  twitter=<twitter id>,
  linkedin=<linkedin id>,
  gplus=<gplus id>]
```

I would like to know how to implement those tex codes in Lyx or Lyx layout?

Comment: `Documents` → `Settings` ...→ `LaTeX Preamble` and just type, or if the stuff  cannot be placed in the preamble, `Ctrl+L` and just type, or go to `Help` → `Customizarion`  → `5. Installing New  Document Classes`→  Ask yourself if worth messing with LyX layouts or it is  just a lot easier edit a .tex  file directly

Comment: @Fran Thanks, I read the Customization part carefully. It takes a lot of time. Finally, I almost get a solution to write the layout file with the 'Argument post:1' format. The key is use the 'post' to set optional arguments [ ] after madatory text { }.